# Complexity of a column resize from NVARCHAR(n) to NVARCHAR(MAX)

Tags: sql-server

There's a table with a column of type `NVARCHAR(3000)`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Items
(
    ItemID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Payload nvarchar(3000) NOT NULL
)
```

The table has ≈10,000,000 records.

What is the complexity of changing this column to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` on a live database?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Items
ALTER COLUMN Payload nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL
```

Is this a cheap operation for SQL Server (affecting only table metadata) or expensive (requires rewrite of all data pages)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expensive operation that will require a rewrite. This 1M row example with a small column value shows 39,147 logical reads.

```
WITH 
     t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t256 AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d)
    ,t16M AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) AS num FROM t256 AS a CROSS JOIN t256 AS b CROSS JOIN t256 AS c)
INSERT INTO dbo.Items WITH(TABLOCKX)
SELECT num, CAST(num AS nvarchar(10))
FROM t16M
WHERE num <= 1000000;
GO

SET STATISTICS IO ON;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Items
    ALTER COLUMN Payload nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL;
GO
```

**UPDATE:**
The change to MAX is a fundamental data type change as illustrated by this script.

Also, the best practice is to explicitly specify NULL or NOT NULL in DDL scripts to avoid inadvertently changing the property and rewrite of existing rows. Similarly, be sure to explicitly specify a COLLATION clause if the existing column collation differs from the database default so that the existing column collation is not accidentally changed. I once ran into the collation difference issue on a multi-billion row table and it wasn't pretty.

Comment: Related: [Why does ALTER COLUMN to NOT NULL cause massive log file growth?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/29522/57105)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and link!